# Firefox dies after a few days of use: CPU limit

Tags: firefox

My Firefox is dying om me every few days.

It says: CPU time limit exceeded (core dumped)

Is there a way I can remove or at least raise this limit?

```
###!!! [Parent][RunMessage] Error: Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost

[Child 867149, MediaDecoderStateMachine #1] WARNING: Decoder=7f46622d9800 Decode error: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_CANCELED (0x806e000a) - RefPtr<MediaSourceTrackDemuxer::SeekPromise> mozilla::MediaSourceTrackDemuxer::DoSeek(const mozilla::media::TimeUnit &): manager is detached.: file /build/firefox-oDiU8w/firefox-96.0+build2/dom/media/MediaDecoderStateMachine.cpp:3568
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
CPU time limit exceeded (core dumped)
```

`ulimit` does not suggest any CPU limit:

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 127356
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 127356
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Firefox: 96.0

Could be related to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1538435

`chrt -o 0 firefox` seemed to work for a while, but no longer works.

I checked if there are any cpu limits set on any process:

```
grep cpu */limits|grep -v 'unlimited.*unlimited'
```

This gave no hits. But this listed all the firefox processes:

```
$ grep realt */limits|grep -v 'unlimited.*unlimited'|G 000
3238579/limits:Max realtime timeout      50000                200000                us
```

this could be the cause. But how do I change that?

Comment: `man 5 limits.conf` will point you in the right direction.

Comment: That's the message? "CPU limit reached"? There's nothing like that in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the Snowflake ("tor") plugin, and the problem stopped.